# How to create a trigger in such that entire old record (existing table) goes to another table before updates happen in the existing table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I'm new to Postgres and trigger functions. I'm trying to create a trigger in postgres where the table ***schema_name1.table_name_abc*** gets inserted or updated every minute. Now before it gets inserted/updated, I want to capture the entire old records (including the newly inserted rows) and move it to another table ***schema_name1.table_name_xyz***

Is it possible to move entire records before update happens also the newly inserted row to another table using trigger?

Below is the query that I'm trying to run. I'm unable to get any logic for the "Insert into" inside ***if conditions***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_name1.table_name_abc()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
BEFORE UPDATE ON schema_name1.table_name_abc
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN
        INSERT INTO  schema_name1.table_name_xyz VALUES(<no idea what to provide here>);
    END IF;
END;

BEFORE INSERT ON schema_name1.table_name_abc
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO  schema_name1.table_name_xyz VALUES(<no idea what to provide here>);
    END IF;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION schema_name1.table_name_abc()
  OWNER TO sys_object_owner;
```

Comment: If it's possible? Sure it is. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @giorgiga - Thank you! I've provided more details.

Answer (score 1):

The values you need are available as `OLD` (eg: the value of `FIELD_NAME` is in `OLD.FIELD_NAME`).

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-trigger.html (specifically, look at Example 42.4)

Comment: Thank you so much! The article is very helpful. However I'm getting "permission denied" error. Does the user have permission to create Trigger?

Comment: Yep: you need the `TRIGGER` privilege